# How to center lists when outputted in python

Tags: python

I have made python code to output pascals triangle with given instructions such as length of triangle, amount of numbers on the first line and what numbers are on the first line, but when printing each list im struggling to find a way to center the lists so the output actually looks like a triangle

This is the code i used, it may not be as tidy as possible or anything but ive tried doing .format with a {:^80} and it still will not work. please help <3

```
import math

print("This code is used to calculate pascals triangle starting from any given number and giving a list as long as needed")

layers = int(input("Enter how many layers you want to calculate (Works best if less than 20):"))
num_amount = int(input("Enter how many numbers you want in the first line :"))

pascal_nums = []
for i in range(0, num_amount):
    cur_num = int(input("Enter number here :"))
    pascal_nums.append(cur_num)
pascal_nums.insert(0, 1)
pascal_nums.append(1)
j = 0
while j <= layers:
    print(" ", end="")
    j += 1
print(*pascal_nums)

for i in range(0, layers):
    for i in range(0, len(pascal_nums)-1):
        temp_num = pascal_nums[i] + pascal_nums[i + 1]
        pascal_nums.remove(pascal_nums[i])
        pascal_nums.insert(i, temp_num)
    pascal_nums.insert(0, 1)
    j = i
    while j <= layers:
        print(" ", end="")
        j += 1
    print(*pascal_nums)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that you are using the same variable name both for the `for-loop` and for the `nested for-loop` which causing a name conflict.

Your nested loop is overriding the value of `i` from the "main" loop.

So, when you do `j = i` it is the remaining value from the second loop rather than the layer number.

You need to change one of them:

- (`x` is the change in this example)

```py
for i in range(0, layers):
    for x in range(0, len(pascal_nums)-1):
        temp_num = pascal_nums[x] + pascal_nums[x + 1]
        pascal_nums.remove(pascal_nums[x])
        pascal_nums.insert(x, temp_num)
    pascal_nums.insert(0, 1)
    j = i
    while j <= layers:
        print(" ", end="")
        j += 1
    print(*pascal_nums)
```

### Output:

```
Enter how many layers you want to calculate (Works best if less than 20):5
Enter how many numbers you want in the first line :5
Enter number here :5
Enter number here :6
Enter number here :5
Enter number here :6
Enter number here :5
      1 5 6 5 6 5 1
      1 11 11 11 6 11 6 1
     1 12 22 22 17 17 17 7 1
    1 13 34 44 39 34 34 24 8 1
   1 14 47 78 83 73 68 58 32 9 1
  1 15 61 125 161 156 141 126 90 41 10 1
```

---

If you want it to be more centered, you need to consider the length of each individual line, comparing to the last line:

- This method considers the number of chars in the line

```py
pascal_lst = []
for i in range(0, layers):
    pascal_lst.append(' '.join([str(num) for num in pascal_nums]))
    for x in range(0, len(pascal_nums)-1):
        temp_num = pascal_nums[x] + pascal_nums[x + 1]
        pascal_nums.remove(pascal_nums[x])
        pascal_nums.insert(x, temp_num)
    pascal_nums.insert(0, 1)

max_length = len(pascal_lst[-1])

for item in pascal_lst:
    diff = max_length - len(item)
    print(diff//2 * ' ' + item)
```

### Output:

```
Enter how many layers you want to calculate (Works best if less than 20):5
Enter how many numbers you want in the first line :5
Enter number here :5
Enter number here :6
Enter number here :5
Enter number here :6
Enter number here :5
            1 5 6 5 6 5 1
         1 11 11 11 6 11 6 1
       1 12 22 22 17 17 17 7 1
      1 13 34 44 39 34 34 24 8 1
    1 14 47 78 83 73 68 58 32 9 1
1 15 61 125 161 156 141 126 90 41 10 1
```

---

### The full code:

```py
print("This code is used to calculate pascals triangle starting from any given number and giving a list as long as needed")

layers = int(input("Enter how many layers you want to calculate (Works best if less than 20):"))
num_amount = int(input("Enter how many numbers you want in the first line :"))

pascal_nums = []
for i in range(0, num_amount):
    cur_num = int(input("Enter number here :"))
    pascal_nums.append(cur_num)
pascal_nums.insert(0, 1)
pascal_nums.append(1)

pascal_lst = []
for i in range(0, layers):
    pascal_lst.append(' '.join([str(num) for num in pascal_nums]))
    for x in range(0, len(pascal_nums)-1):
        temp_num = pascal_nums[x] + pascal_nums[x + 1]
        pascal_nums.remove(pascal_nums[x])
        pascal_nums.insert(x, temp_num)
    pascal_nums.insert(0, 1)

max_length = len(pascal_lst[-1])

for item in pascal_lst:
    diff = max_length - len(item)
    print(diff//2 * ' ' + item)
```

Comment: Thats perfect thank you so much its worked. im just wondering if you could explain what the line 'pascal_lst.append(' '.join([str(num) for num in pascal_nums]))' actually does so i know for next time

Comment: The [join](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp) method joins a list of strings to one string. `join` function takes a list of strings, but `pascal_nums` is list of `int`s. I converted it to list of strings by using [List Comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)

Comment: perf, ty for your help

Comment: Happy to help :)